# Tail Recursive function or not

Tags: lisp, scheme, tail-recursion

Can anyone help me with this please?

```
(define f (lambda (x)
  (cond
    ((null? x) 0)
    (#t (+ (* (car x) (car x)) (f (cdr x)))))))
```

I couldn't understand if this function is tail recursive or not?
If it is, what is the reason?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion

Comment: No, you have to keep the results of (* (car x) (car x)) on the stack while you wait for (f (cdr x)) to be evaluated. In a tail call you could throw it away and get the same answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not tail recursive because the last thing the function does before returning is to evaluate `(+ ...)`. In order to be tail recursive the last operation before returning has to be the recursive call.

Making a function tail recursive usually involves a helper function which takes an accumulator parameter:

```
(define f0 (lambda (x acc)
  (if (null? x)
      acc
      (f0 (cdr x) (+ acc (* (car x)(car x)))))))

(define f (lambda (x)
  (f0 x 0)))
```

Comment: Hey can you please provide the tail recursive code so i can understand it more easily.

Comment: You don't need an aculumulator per se, just some way to pass the state of the recursion along to the next call.